Modify source data rxjs
I have observable and I want to modify source (of({lastId, lastCreatedAt}) part) after each iteration of iterateAsync, but return data from listRequest, is it possible?
export const fromListIterator = <T = unknown>(
  listRequest: IteratorFunction<T>,
  limit?: number,
): Observable<T> => {
  return of({ lastId: '', lastCreatedAt: 0 }).pipe(
    mergeMap((source) => [
      from(
        new Iterator<T>(
          () =>
            listRequest(
              { sort: ['id', 'created_at'], page: undefined },
              {
                filter: [
                  new CursorPaginationFilterStrategy(
                    source.lastId,
                    source.lastCreatedAt,
                  ),
                ],
              },
            ),
          limit,
        ).iterateAsync(),
      ).pipe(mergeMap((r) => lastValueFrom(of(r)))),
    ]),
    mergeAll(),
  );
};


Yes, it's possible to modify the source data ({ lastId, lastCreatedAt }) after each iteration and return data from the listRequest. However, you need to handle it in a way that each iteration updates the source data and then feeds it into the next iteration.
To achieve this, you can use expand instead of mergeMap. expand allows you to recursively call a function, where you can modify the state (source) after each iteration and continue until a termination condition is met.
import { of, from, Observable, lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import { expand, mergeMap, takeWhile, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const fromListIterator = <T = unknown>(
  listRequest: IteratorFunction<T>,
  limit?: number,
): Observable<T> => {
  return of({ lastId: '', lastCreatedAt: 0 }).pipe(
    expand((source) =>
      from(
        new Iterator<T>(
          () =>
            listRequest(
              { sort: ['id', 'created_at'], page: undefined },
              {
                filter: [
                  new CursorPaginationFilterStrategy(
                    source.lastId,
                    source.lastCreatedAt,
                  ),
                ],
              },
            ),
          limit,
        ).iterateAsync(),
      ).pipe(
        // map the result and update source
        map((result) => {
          const lastItem = result[result.length - 1]; // assuming last item has lastId and lastCreatedAt
          return {
            data: result,
            source: lastItem
              ? { lastId: lastItem.id, lastCreatedAt: lastItem.created_at }
              : null,
          };
        }),
        takeWhile(({ source }) => !!source), // continue until there's no more data
        map(({ data }) => data) // extract the data
      )
    ),
    mergeAll() // flatten the observable of arrays
  );
};


expand: This operator is used to recursively emit the next value by calling the provided function. It allows us to update the source after each iteration.

takeWhile: Ensures that the recursion stops when no more data is available (i.e., source becomes null).

map: Maps the result of each iteration to extract the data and update the source for the next iteration.


